# WooCommerce shipping cost based on cart item count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to count shipping cost based on number of products add on cart like,

If I purchase one mobile then it will count shipping cost as 2.5 and after more than two or two mobile I purchased then shipping cost will be 5.0

```
<?php
    $qty(1) * 2.5 = 2.5
    $qty(2) * 2.5 = 5.0
    $qty(3) * 2.5 = 5.0
?>
```

So is there any idea or suggestion how to count the shipping cost based on number of products ?

Comment: You need to create custom shipping method for this - i thinks this links help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sorry to reply you late but i also tried in many ways through custom code but i did not get any success so i find out plugin for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Updated:**
>
> As your question is a bit unclear, you could just need to add **`[qty]*2.5`** in the **Flat rate** shipping method **cost** (for each shipping zone) in your wooCommerce shipping settings.
>
> **But it will not work if you have 2 different items in cart** like: **`item1 (qty 1) + item2 (qty 1)`**

**So this answer will do it in all cases:**

1) First you will need to set a **"Flat rate"** shipping method for each Shipping Zones which cost will be set to **`2.5`** (in your WooCommerce shipping settings).

2) Adding this code that will calculate for each cart items (based on the total quantity of items) the new updated shipping cost:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_flat_rate_cost_calculation', 10, 2 );
function custom_flat_rate_cost_calculation( $rates, $package )
{
    // The cart count (total items in cart)
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $taxes = array();

    // If there is more than 1 cart item
    if( $cart_count > 1 ){
        // Iterating through each shipping rate
        foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate_values){
            // Targeting "Flat Rate" shipping method
            if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate_values->method_id ) {
                // Set the new calculated rate cost
                $rates[$rate_id]->cost = number_format($rates[$rate_id]->cost * $cumulated_active_quantity, 2);
                // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_id]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                        $taxes[$key] = number_format( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] * $cumulated_active_quantity, 2 );
                        $has_taxes = true;
                    } else {
                        $has_taxes = false;
                    }
                }
                if( $has_taxes )
                    $rates[$rate_id]->taxes = $taxes; 
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works

> **You will need to refresh shipping zones caches:** disabling the Flat rate, then save. And enabling back this rate and save.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom fee: Add to theme functions.php or use a plugin

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );

function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $price_per_mobile = 2.5;
    $shipcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total * $price_per_mobile);   
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Total Shipping Cost', $shipcharge, true, '' );

}
```

Comment: thanks i got one plugin so it's working now but thanks for sharing answer with us.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead with Woocommerce filter  `woocommerce_package_rates`. Where you can customize all the shipping rates available in cart page.

Here is the code for adding extra cost to all items for both domestic and international shipement

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wf_modify_rate', 10, 3);
function wf_modify_rate( $available_shipping_methods, $package ){
    $origin_country = 'US';
    $amount_to_add_domestic = 10;
    $amount_to_add_inter_national = 20;

    $amount_to_add = ($package['destination']['country'] == $origin_country) ? 
    $amount_to_add_domestic : $amount_to_add_inter_national;

    $item_count = 0;
    foreach ($package['contents'] as $key => $item) {
        $item_count += $item['quantity'];
    }

    foreach ($available_shipping_methods as $methord_name => $methord) {
        $available_shipping_methods[$methord_name]->cost += ($amount_to_add*$item_count);
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```